# Java unicode strange behaviour

Tags: java, html, unicode, character-encoding, emoji

I'm using HttpURLConnection to make requests to the twitter's API. The API returns a json with all the data encoded with UTF-8 (you can see that in the headers of the response). And I show the data in a .jsp (html).

I read the response (json) with this piece of code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    // Append line to 'res', so I can have a string with all the json
    res.append(inputLine);
    // Print the line for debugging
    System.out.println(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

Now, here comes the problem. Some values inside the json (for now just a String) are emojis, so they should be represented as unicode characters. And that's exactly what happens, at least with some of them. Here's an example with a user's name:

**Original twitter text:**

[image]

**What I get from the API's response:**

```
"name":"\uD83C\uDF52UserName"
```

**How it is finally displayed in the .jsp:**

[image]

It works fine with this emoji. The name is shown as it is shown in twitter. But look at the text of the following tweet. It's as if the unicode is duplicated but the second one is not displayed, or somethig strange. Note that in eclipse's console, you see `??`, but when it loads the .jsp, the emoji shows itself as it should. That's not the problem, it's just the encoding of the console, I guess (although it is indicative that something is wrong with that unicode, because in the first example it has shown then unicode, and not the `??`).

**Original twitter tweet:**

[image]

**What I get from the API's response:**

"text":"?? Segons l'U.S. Department of Justice, els infants que es crien sense pare són:\n\n?? 63% de suïcidis.\n?? 90% d'indigents.\n?? 85% de desordres en el comportament.\n?? 71% de l'abandonament escolar.\n?? 70% de les detencions juvenils.\n?? 75% d'abús de drogues.\n?? 75% dels violadors."}

**How it is finally displayed in the .jsp:**

[image]

The emojis are displayed correctly, but there's always a `?` after them, and I don't know why.

Also, I should mention that, in the .jsp, in order to show convert the unicode to html-compatible-code, I use [this library](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java). You can see the difference between using the method to parse the unicode to hex and not using it here:

[image]

[image]

**Any idea what's happening here?**

The emojis mentioned are: (U+1F352) ♦️(U+2666) ❗️(U+2757)

Comment: I think you need to provide a source of these problematic emojis for people to help diagnose this

Comment: @g00se you mean the code of the emojis?

Comment: I mean the url you're reading with emojis in it

Comment: @g00se I have already provided the text I get from that url, I don't think it will help in the least to post the entire response.

Comment: I read twice your question, and I do not get what you are asking, and what it is the problem. Could you check the numeric values of the `?` characters (as soon as possible in the text flow). Possibly you have some control character (e.g. tab)

Comment: I think it's very clear what's the problem: "The emojis are displayed correctly, but there's always a ? after them, and I don't know why".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. That `?` is a the character `65039` in decimal, so what I've done is replace that character by a space. Now the emojis are shown as I wanted, without that sign after them.

```
String strFinal = res2.toString().replace((char)65039, ' ');
```

[image]